# Can someone tell me what kind of reptile is this?

Tags: species-identification, herpetology

[image]

It was found in El Paso Texas. It was very scared and weak when I found it. But I bought it a small aquarium and some food to make sure it’s ok before I let it go. It’s tail is broken off. It have blue and yellow dots on top of it and I think it’s a male. Can someone tell me about this lizard?

Comment: Yeah, I agree that it looks like a Fence Lizard.  The "scared and weak" is almost certainly related to the missing tail - indications that it had a close encounter with a predator like a house cat or maybe a bird.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you have in your a hand a lizard of the Genus *Sceloporus* , and perhaps *[Sceloporus occidentalis longipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sceloporus_occidentalis_longipes)*.

Commonly called the Great Basin fence lizard is a subspecies of the western fence lizard . It is genrally found in the western part of North America

[image]

[image]

Here is  a link to a guide of [small spiny lizards](http://www.californiaherps.com/identification/lizardsid/smallspiny.id.html) .